# "Run | Debug" option is NOT showing above each test in Eclipse using TestNG and Selenium

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

"Run | Debug" option is NOT showing above each test in Eclipse using TestNG and Selenium[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XzTe.png)

I had tried adding new version of TestNG but it didn't work also checked with newer version of eclipss.